# Windows network takes long time to access

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, domain

I have 4 Winodws XP systems connected in a domain with Windows 2003 server. Domain name is "SoftGenIndia". We are using Star topology. I have checked all the cables and connections, all are OK. What happening is that when i try to open the computer on domain it takes long time to show the shares (around 2-3 mins).

Is there anything i am missing? Can anybody provide solution on this.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Regards
Mohammad Irfan
http://softwaregenius.net

Answer (score 0):

First point to check is that all of the domain controller is set up as a DNS server and that all of the clients are configured to use *only that* as their DNS server. It should forward on their DNS requests if they need to access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Check for ip configuration on clients

Check clients DNS and gateway

Test cable quality with `pathping` from client to DC.

example:

`pathping 192.168.1.1`

If you get some packets loss, you have to recheck cable or jack.